# xdg-settings not setting default-web-browser in gentoo

Tags: gentoo, xdgutils

I'm trying to get `xdg-open` to using chromium to open urls instead of firefox. I noticed that `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` returns `chromium.desktop` when it should be `chromium-browser-chromium.desktop`.

Following the instructions [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Default_Applications#Setting_the_default_application_via_xdg-settings) I tried `xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser-chromium.desktop`, which runs with no errors. However when I run `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` it stills shows `chromium.desktop`, and `xdg-open "http://www.example.com"` still uses firefox. I have confirmed that `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser-chromium.desktop` is present. Rebooting the machine does not fix the problem.

For now, I've created a "chromium.desktop" sym-link to "chromium-browser-chromium.desktop", but it would be nice to know why `xdg-settings` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

`xdg-*` utilities are just quite simple POSIX shell scripts that try their best to handle simple common DE tasks in a seemingly standardized way. But the truth is, that every DE uses its own tools and knobs, and every installation uses different mix of them, so in this case it seems that you're using some non-standard desktop environment, which these poor utilities just cannot handle.

Anyway, if you want to debug your specific issue, run those scripts with `sh -vx` (eg. `sh -vx /usr/bin/xdg-settings`) and it will tell you exactly what those scripts are doing and at which point they fail.